# Genymotion can't install things

Tags: android, genymotion

I saw people say drag into emulator can install.....
but why only copied? is that have any solution??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoFwz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's comes the story.
Installing works only on APK's (Undamaged) and the case you have, might be of a damaged APK.
See [here](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Interacting_with_virtual_devices/Drag_and_drop.htm) in detail.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your app for arm7 or arm. Genymotion x86